# Get all iOS apps and their information through GET request from a specified developer

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, get, app-store-connect

Is there a url like `developer.apple.com/developers/apps?id=12345` where `12345` is the developer's ID that gives information about that developer's apps?  By developer ID I mean like how apps are usually navigated in URLs like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appname/id12345?mt=8 and the id is after `id` in the url.  I'd like to receive a JSON response through an ajax request because I'm working in JavaScript, but I'm okay with different responses.

For example, a website like [this](http://www.trackany.com/ios) shows App Developers' apps.

It doesn't have to be an official way, but I don't want a risk of the site expiring.

Comment: I don't believe there is and I think it would be scary if there is as it could show information not wanted to be shared

Comment: @JamesBlack Then how does [this](http://www.trackany.com/ios/developer/528960777) work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get all "content" from a developer via the "artist" link:

https://itunes.apple.com/artist/idXXXXXXXX

For example if you open the iTunes app and search for Apple, you will get a full link like this one:

https://itunes.apple.com/de/artist/apple/id284417353?mt=12

You can leave out the country (DE) and the artist name (Apple) and the variable (?mt=12). The link works with the ID only, too, however you need the /artist. The only question is, how you will get the ID. I compared our own ID with all data we have available, and it is neither the  from iTMSTransporter nor other data I found on iTunesconnect.

Comment: So you can retrieve information from that link through GET?

Comment: You only get the page. I think all App Store related services use their very own service to convert the information. (appfigures.com, appannie.com, apptrace.com etc.) Maybe you should contact them, how they do it.